# With Fullpage.js, can y-position inside sections be reported during scrollOverflow scrolling? (using iscroll-probe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, iscroll

I'm using the latest version of fullpage.js with the scrollOverflow option set to true. Like this example...
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html

Fullpage.js uses iscroll.js for this option, and I have included the "probe" version of iscroll. Like this example...
http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/probe/

Can iscroll-probe report the **y position** of whichever **fullpage "section" is currently being scrolled**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible. Although the iScroll library has [some bugs that were solved for its use in fullpage.js](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/1041) with the scrolloverflow.js fork. I would suggest you to do those changes yourself in the iScroll Probe.

Regarding how to get the scrolling possition, just take a look at the source example you provided to know which iscroll events to use.

Then, just take the iscroll instance of the section that can be extracted with:

```
$('.fp-section.active').find('.fp-scrollable').data('iscrollInstance');
```

Or from the active slide:

```
$('.fp-section.active').find('.fp-slide.active').find('.fp-scrollable').data('iscrollInstance');
```

And use the iScroll option `probeType:3` as detailed in their docs. To do so extend the default scrolloverflow options with the `scrollOverflowOptions` param.

And mixing all together...

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1432/)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    scrollOverflow:true,
    scrollOverflowOptions: {
        probeType: 3
    },
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
       var iscroll = $('.fp-section.active').find('.fp-scrollable').data('iscrollInstance');

       if(iscroll && typeof iscroll !== undefined){
            iscroll.on('scroll', getScroll);
       }
    }
});

function getScroll(){
   console.log(this.y);
   $('#position').text(this.y);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro. First, being a first-time poster, I must thank you for your response and help. For years always looked for answers on stackoverflow, but never contributed questions or answers. (it's time to start pulling my own weight).

Comment: Second, this definitely will help to solve my problem, and I am testing it in my project now, but there seems to be a problem already in the jsfiddle you created.
Why do you get locked into the second section when you scroll down?
I've forked the fiddle and added a couple more sections. http://jsfiddle.net/fv0ee9xg/
When you hit the first scrolloverflow in section 2, you can not get to section3 or back to section 1.

Comment: As i said, iScroll is buggy. You'll need to make the changes in the probe version according to the link I posted to be able to use it with fullpage.js.
Fullpage.js uses a fork of iScroll that solves those bugs.

Comment: I didn't understand at first, but I your link to github explains it. Thank you. 
I will post a fully working jsfiddle with the edited version of scrolloverflow.js (iscroll.js) just in case someone else needs it in the future.

Thanks again for the help and for the awesome plugin.

Comment: Hi, in this pull request to fullPage repo, we have a scrolloverflow-probe.js, https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/pull/2531 I've tested on my project, and work like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is impossible, because both plugins will try to work with the same 'element', at the same time, and in ways different. So, it'll conflict each others, of course. I'm sorry, but try another way.  :/

Comment: Never underestimate the power of fullpage.js! :) My answer above